# Object graph serialization in memory

Tags: java

Say I have this object instantiated as an example:

```java
    BasicAWSCredentials credentials =
            new BasicAWSCredentials(objectStoreAccessKey, objectStoreSecretKey);
    AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .withEndpointConfiguration(
                    new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(objectStoreEndpoint, objectStoreRegion))
            .build();
```

AmazonS3 is not serializable *per se* (and the other similar clients) is there a way to have its complete object graph serialized as such it can be used across different instances of the application and/or other processes.

Comment: This is one of those *almost impossible* things with the JVM, and to my understanding only Terracotta was able to achieve it but it's not opensource, I don't know any open source code that have anything close.